# QProgressBar : Change color while keeping OS style

Tags: c++, qt

I know that Qt uses by default the OS style for decorating a `QProgressBar`.

I am wondering if there is a way to change the color of a `QProgressBar` while keeping the OS style.

I tried several methods as showned below.

*Changing the palette*:

```
QPalette palette = myProgressBar->palette();
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Highlight, someColor); // setColor() did the same
myProgressBar->setPalette(palette);
```

*Changing directly the style*:

```
QPalette palette = myProgressBar->palette();
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Highlight, someColor); // setColor() did the same
myProgressBar->style()->polish(palette);
```

But both methods was completely ignored and nothing has changed.

The only way I found to change the color of the `QProgressBar` is by setting a style sheet via `setStyleSheet()`. The problem is that it ignores the OS style at the same time.

I think it is possible to **approximately** replicate the OS style in a style sheet but I don't know if it is possible to directly apply the OS style and only change the color palette.

I would be very grateful for any helpful answer.

---

**EDIT:** The OS is not fixed. I am trying to make it work under Windows but the application may/will run under another OS (some Linux distribution).

Comment: @hyde I did not have provided a full MCVE to not add unnecessary noise and focus only on the problem. As you said, displaying a single widget with Qt does not hurt. Moreover, my question is not restricted to C++ (it is more about Qt, no matter the language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which style you are using. In general Qt specific themes (like fusion) can be easily customized simply by changing the palette (*Note that different styles may use different palette roles*).

However, for OS specific styles (like `QWindowsVistaStyle`), you simply cannot do it.
The reason is that the style implementation ignores the palette and use colors from the OS theme.

For instance if you look at the implementation at `QWindowsXPStyle` you will find calls to `GetThemeColor()` which returns the color from the OS.

These OS specific styles also cannot use stylesheets correctly, that's why if yo use a stylesheet, the widget will fallback to a default style.

I believe your only solution would be to use [`QProxyStyle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html), but you may have to rewrite the code to draw  parts of widget you want to customize.